# MySQL Workbench - Trouble to export the structure and data

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, workbench

### What I am trying

I trying to export my database with the structure and data. But when I try to export, throw this error at my screen.
[image]

### What Am I using?

- MariaDB - MySQL
- Docker
  [image]
  [image]

### MySQL DUMP Version

```
mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

```
mysql -V 
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

### Workbench Preferences - Administration

[image]

### Workbench Preferences - MySQL

[image]

Comment: And what does `~/Documents/mysqldump --version` say?

Comment: @emix ```mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))```